# phpDesigner 8 FTP

Tags: ftp, phpdesigner

so I thought I will give this software a try after years with Dreamweaver, but I got a problem browsing my files with its ftp browser.
When I log in with a different ftp client, I can see my files without any problem, but in the phpD client, I can only browse "aspnet_client".
Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems some broken FTP clients cant get the correct path to your username directory, this specific client trying to access the root directory, all you have to do is provide him your ftp path (instead of the default '/'), usually - your username.